# Calling OnNext when a property changes

Tags: system.reactive

I think I'm being dense here. I have two classes, one of which contains a list of the other - here's a cut down version:

```
Class Service
  Private _ratesList As New List(Of Rate)
  Public Property Rates As IEnumerable(Of Rate)
  Public Sub AddRate(rate As Rate)
    _ratesList.Add(rate)
  End Sub
End Class

Class Rate        
  Private _priority As Integer
  Public Property Priority As Integer
    Get
      Return _priority
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As Integer)
      _priority = Value
    End Set
  End Property  
End Class
```

I need the parent Service object to be notified whenever one of the Rate objects in its list has its Priority changed. The following does what I want:

```
Class Service
  Private _ratesList As New List(Of Rate)
  Public Property Rates As IEnumerable(Of Rate)
  Public Sub AddRate(rate As Rate)
    rate.PriorityChanges.Subscribe(AddressOf HandleRatePriorityChange)
    _ratesList.Add(rate)
  End Sub

  Private Sub HandleRatePriorityChange(rate As Rate)
    ' Do something
  End Sub
End Class

Class Rate        

  Private _priorityChanges As New Subject(Of Rate)
  Public ReadOnly Property PriorityChanges As IObservable(Of Rate)
    Get
      Return _priorityChanges
    End Get
  End Property

  Private _priority As Integer
  Public Property Priority As Integer
    Get
      Return _priority
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As Integer)
      _priority = Value
      _priorityChanges.OnNext(Me)
    End Set
  End Property  
End Class
```

So the rate class calls OnNext every time the property is set to a new value.

My concern is that I'm using a Subject instead of (for example) Observable.Create. What's the recommended way of doing this? I'm sure it's blindingly obvious, but I've reached the state where I can't see the wood for the trees!

Comment: You may want to read my blog post: [To Use Subject or Not To Use Subject](http://davesexton.com/blog/post/To-Use-Subject-Or-Not-To-Use-Subject.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for that, very helpful. Sounds like Subject is the way to go. I was put off by the very comments you mentioned in your post, and the suggestion that at some point Subject might be rewritten with poor performance.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about `Subject<T>` being rewritten with poor performance. By Rx 1.0 the team was concentrating on correctness rather than performance, so locks were used to ensure the Rx grammar and serialized notifications. By Rx 2.0, the team removed the locks and relaxed the grammar constraints to greatly improve performance, and made similar changes throughout Rx. I highly doubt they'll revert back.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rxteam/archive/2012/03/12/reactive-extensions-v2-0-beta-available-now.aspx

Comment: To my previous point, a major consequence of the performance improvements to `Subject<T>` is that you're responsible now for ensuring serialized notifications (and to a lesser extent, the Rx grammar) yourself. So just be sure that you don't make overlapping calls to `OnNext`, for instance. And if you do, be sure to apply the `Synchronize` operator before querying.

Comment: And one more thing: you should hide the "subjectness" of the field in your getter with the `AsObservable` operator to ensure that it can't be cast to `Subject<T>` externally; e.g., `Return _priorityChanges.AsObservable()`.

Comment: Thank you Dave. I was aware of the need for AsObservable, I just left it out of the example for simplicity. I hadn't considered the synchronise point though, so thanks for the tip. If you'd like to make your post an answer I'd be happy to mark it as such?

Comment: Consider using a `BehaviorSubject`, not just a `Subject`.  IOW replace your `_priority` and `_priorityChanges` pair of fields with a single `_priority` `BehaviorSubject` field.  Your Getter would return `_priority.Value` and your setter would just call `_priority.OnNext(Value)`.  One less thing for you to juggle this way.

Comment: I agree with @Brandon.

Comment: Noted Brandon, thanks. I think I also saw this in Dave's blog. Not something I'd realised before as I'd dismissed using Subjects until I came across this requirement

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Dave Sexton for his very informative blog post [To Use Subject or Not To Use Subject](http://davesexton.com/blog/post/To-Use-Subject-Or-Not-To-Use-Subject.aspx). The answer is that my concerns about using Subject were misplaced in these specific circumstances, but please do read the blog for more information

Answer (score 0):

In your case using `BehaviorSubject` maybe the most simple design to get you to your goal (as suggested by Brandon). In which case this looks like a winner.

In a wider view of a design or architecture, you *may* want to consider existing event patterns for propagating change notification. The `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and the `ObservableCollection(Of T)` provide events to expose change notification. These are very popular in WPF, however they exist in the BCL so can be used in non-wpf applications.

If you chose to adopt these, then you can transition to Rx using the FromEvent factories, which most people wrap in a custom extension method. In your simple example above, this will however be far more code for no real gain. In a wider code base, this maybe of use especially if you are in WPF or if you use a weaver like Fody to do the event raising automatically.

As a total side note, please *remember to dispose of your subscriptions* if you also expose a way to remove or clear items. I see that in your example you drop the returned subscription.

Comment: Thanks Lee. In this case there was no existing event model to latch on to - this was being written from scratch to us Rx, and introducing an event pattern so we could avoid using events seemed... less than optimal. We've used that technique a lot in other areas though. I've also found your intro to Rx site very useful, by the way, so thanks for that!

Comment: Good to hear. Just posting that answer for completeness (in case you were already using events). In your case I then strongly recommend using Brandon's approach.